# jquery How to change cursor after animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, cursor

When I click on the div `#cart-button` and the animation has ended, the cursor has to change to normal instead of pointer and return to pointer when clicked again. (`cursor: pointer;` is the default style for the div in the CSS file).

I tried to put `document.getElementById("cart-button").style.cursor="pointer";` after the `else` tag but I'm doing something wrong.

The js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var expanded = false;
    $('#cart-button').click(function() {
        if (!expanded) {
            $(this).animate({ 'top' : '380px' }, { duration : 400 });
            expanded = true;
        }
        else {
            $(this).animate({ 'top' : '226px' }, { duration: 400 });
            expanded = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by calling an anonymous function after the animation completes like so:

For your if statement:

```
$(this).animate({top: '380px'}, 400, function() { // anonymous function
    $('#cart-button').css({cursor: 'default'}); // sets cursor to default immediately after animation completes
});
expanded = true;
```

and for your else statement:

```
$(this).animate({top: '226px'}, 400, function() {
    $('#cart-button').css({cursor: 'default'});
});
expanded = false;
```

I believe that the "normal" cursor in css is referred to as *default*, so you'd want to set it to that.

I also changed some formatting of the code, but feel free to use whatever way you prefer.